# This error keep on appearing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

at first everything work perfectly fine..but then after 1 month not open the application,this error appear.I didnt do any changes.This is the error,I try to fix it.but still,the problem is there..

```
01-18 17:54:43.271: W/dalvikvm(1244): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a51b90)
01-18 17:54:44.401: D/dalvikvm(1244): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 124K, 7% free 3060K/3272K, paused 764ms, total 782ms
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Process: com.sabry.javabmi, PID: 1244
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sabry.javabmi/com.sabry.javabmi.bmiLogger}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.sabry.javabmi.bmiLogger.initializeApp(bmiLogger.java:60)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.sabry.javabmi.bmiLogger.onCreate(bmiLogger.java:37)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     ... 11 more
01-18 17:54:52.581: I/Process(1244): Sending signal. PID: 1244 SIG: 9
```

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.sabry.javabmi.R;
import com.sabry.javabmi.bmiLogger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class bmiLogger extends Activity {

private Intent currentIntent;
private EditText edtWeight;
private EditText edtTime;
private EditText edtDate;
private Button btnChart;
private Calendar c;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bmi);
    initializeApp();
}

private void initializeApp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    edtWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtWeight);
    edtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDate);
    edtTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTime);

    c = Calendar.getInstance();

    currentIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = currentIntent.getExtras();

    if(extras != null){
    edtWeight.setText(extras.getString("weight"));
    }

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    String FILENAME = "bmi_log.csv";
    File file = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath( FILENAME );
    if( !file.exists() ) {
      // Disable the Chart Button
      btnChart.setEnabled( false );
    }

}


DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet( DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth ) {
      c.set( Calendar.YEAR, year );
      c.set( Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear );
      c.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth );
      setCurrentDateOnView();
    }
  };

  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet( TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute ) {
          c.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay );
          c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, minute );
          setCurrentDateOnView();
        }
      };

public void dateOnClick( View view ) {
        new DatePickerDialog(bmiLogger.this, date,
            c.get( Calendar.YEAR ), c.get( Calendar.MONTH ), c.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH    ) ).show();
    }

public void timeOnClick( View view ) {
    new TimePickerDialog( bmiLogger.this, time,
        c.get( Calendar.HOUR ), c.get( Calendar.MINUTE ), false ).show();
  }

public void setCurrentDateOnView(){
    //First alternative to make date and time
    //int month, day, year, hours, minutes ;
    //year = c.get( Calendar.YEAR);
    //month = c.get( Calendar.MONTH);
    //day = c.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //hours = c.get( Calendar.HOUR);
    //minutes = c.get( Calendar.MINUTE);

    //Second approach
    String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
    edtDate.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime())); 

    String timeFormat = "hh:mm a";
    SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat, Locale.US);
    edtTime.setText(stf.format(c.getTime())); 

}

public void saveLogOnClick( View view ) {
    String FILENAME = "bmi_log.csv";
    String entry = edtDate.getText().toString() + "," +
        edtTime.getText().toString() + "," +
        edtWeight.getText().toString() + "\n";
    try {
      FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput( FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND );
      out.write( entry.getBytes() );
      out.close();
      toastIt( "Entry Saved" );
      btnChart.setEnabled( true );
    } catch( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


private void toastIt(String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(bmiLogger.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void switchToCalc(View v){
    finish();
}

}
```

Comment: What is the line 60 of at `bmiLogger.java`?

Comment: Nothing at line 60 of that file, but assuming it's the correct file and the line numbers are slightly off I'd suggest breakpointing where you attempt to open bmi_log.csv and see if it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
  btnChart.setEnabled( false );
```

you have not initialized / set your btnChart object.

Answer (score 0):

In your logcat below indicates the issue is at Line 60 which indicates the initialization of btnChart is an issue. In your code, no where the initialization appeared for btnChart.

Please initialize `btnChart` in `bmiLogger.Java` in `initializeApp()` and check

```
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-18 17:54:44.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1244):     at com.sabry.javabmi.bmiLogger.initializeApp(bmiLogger.java:60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to initialize the button object before using it.

```
btnChart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
```